# RequestJS pass a content-type: application/json

Tags: node.js, requestjs

I'm looking a way to pass a content-type in RequestJS using with Nodejs.

Right now I have this as params:

```
'use strict';
request = require('request'),

app.register = function(req, res) {
 request.post({
   headers: {'Content-Type' : 'application/json'},
   url: 'my.url.here',
   form: req.body,
 }).pipe(res);
}
```

But for some reason the server it still says it's a content-type text/xml..
Anyone can tell me how to customize this?

Comment: also, why are you sending req.body in the form option, if you're setting content-type to application/json? json != form params. How does requirejs tie into this?

Comment: Req.body is parameter that pass in the controler...

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `json` option, not `form`, and you don't need to set the content type, the json option does that for you.

```
request.post({
  url: 'my.url.here',
  json: req.body
}).pipe(res);
```

Comment: Thanks, Kevin  that solve it,just new to this requestjs :)